# Measuring time within a script

Tags: shell-script, time

[This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/228801/measure-script-execution-time) shows how to measure the time it takes to run a script. In my case, I am interested in measuring time  **between two points within a script**. Here is an example of how I would like to use this:

```
start_measuring_time
Line 1
Line 2
..
Line N
stop_measuring_time
show_elapsed_time
```

I would like the displayed time to be **human readable** (secs, min, hours, days, etc.), if possible. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `date` util:

```
#!/bin/bash

start_measuring_time() {
  read s1 s2 < <(date +'%s %N')
}

stop_measuring_time() {
  read e1 e2 < <(date +'%s %N')
}

show_elapsed_time() {
  echo "$((e1-s1)) seconds, $((e2-s2)) nanoseconds"
}

start_measuring_time
sleep 2
stop_measuring_time
show_elapsed_time
```

Comment: This will produce errors: the beginning and ending times need to be interpreted as seconds + nanoseconds **together**, not separately - you can get things like negative values otherwise.

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19866/linux-patches-related-to-time-measurement-accuracy/19899#19899) for a way to solve this.

Comment: I had to downvote since its not comletely correct answer, correct it gives negative values at times but in your question why aren't you putting echo before `Tend-Tstart`  and after `$(`

Answer (score 12):

You could just use `time`:

```
time (
Line 1
Line 2
..
Line N
)
```

I think the output of time is human readable as is, but if your script is going to measure in days, etc., then check out `man time` for formatting options for the output.

Comment: Thanks @frabjous! I think I will accept @enzotib's answer because it allows me to measure time in general control flows (i.e. not just in linear flows).

Answer (score 1):

Sample to try timerscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

#timing in minutes with %m
start=`date +%m`
echo 'Start:' $start
#do something e.g. wait for 1.30 minutes 
sleep 90

`end=`date +%m`
echo 'End: '$end
echo 'runtime: '$runtime
```