# How to average time commands?

Tags: performance, time, benchmark, time-utility

I am `time`ing some of my commands. Now to average the measures, I'd like to run and time my commands a specified number of times, and get the results with a calculated mean and standard deviation. The result would be like:

```
avgtime -n 100 my_command

real    0m5.388s stdev 0m0.068s
user    0m5.380s stdev 0m0.067s
sys     0m0.004s stdev 0m0.000s
```

Is there a UNIX tool for this?
Does GNU/Linux have one?

Answer (score 12):

You can to try use the timeit module, available in any system with Python:

```
$ python -m timeit "__import__('os').system('my command here')"
10 loops, best of 3: 591 msec per loop
```

Comment: using `os.system()`, causes the overhead of calling/creating a shell with each command. Probably better use subprocess.call()

Comment: true, but would be likely constant-ish anyway

Answer (score 8):

[Hyperfine](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine) is another option.

Sample usage:

```
hyperfine --warmup 3 'my_command'
```

See [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/603897/how-to-measure-average-execution-time-of-a-script/1482413#1482413).

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly a UNIX or GNU/Linux tool, but you could quite comfortably use the [**R** software environment for statistical computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) for this. (I cannot [find anything more specific for your task, though](http://rseek.org).)

**Edit** How could I doubt it, there of course is a benchmark package for `R`: [`rbenchmark`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rbenchmark/).  It apparently wraps `system.time()` which you could also just use directly.  [Or have a look at this, a simple stopwatch function pair.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1716344/993018)  Also see ["Executing a system command" @Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Execute_a_system_command#R) (or don't, it's `system("command")`.)

**Edit2** I just saw [this question, "Measuring time within a script"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18274/11539) in the right "Related" column, this could be used, too, i.e. take time, do for-loop (`N` times), take time again, calculate timespan, divide by `N`.  (Even easier, try `time ( for-loop )`, parse its output, divide by `N`).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `R` to quickly compute the mean, standard-deviation and other interesting values.

For example, you can use GNU time to write several runtime measurements into a CSV file:

```
function measure
{
  f=$1; shift
  n=$2; shift
  echo wall,user,sys,rss > "$f"
  for i in $(seq $n); do
    /usr/bin/time --output "$f" --append --format '%e,%U,%S,%M' "$@" >/dev/null
  done
}
```

Then you can generate the values with R like this:

```
Rscript --vanilla -e "b=read.csv(file='$f');summary(b);sapply(b, sd);"
```

I've created a small [benchmark script](https://github.com/gsauthof/utility/blob/master/benchmark.sh) that also does some pretty printing of the R output, e.g.:

```
$ benchmark.sh 100 ./some_prog arg1 arg2
n=100 | min    | Q1     | med    | mean   | Q3     | max    | std
wall  | 0.0400 | 0.0400 | 0.0500 | 0.0471 | 0.0500 | 0.0800 | 0.00624
user  | 0.0400 | 0.0400 | 0.0400 | 0.0426 | 0.0400 | 0.0700 | 0.00562
sys   | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0.00000
rss   | 2608   | 2657   | 2704   | 2728   | 2764   | 2920   | 95.06524
```

Answer (score 3):

Two more options (both now available in debian et al.):

- [multitime](https://tratt.net/laurie/src/multitime/) ([on
  github](https://github.com/ltratt/multitime)), as in `multitime -q -n 10 sleep 1` (from
  https://superuser.com/a/1301756/129608)
- linux-perf ([wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Counting_with_perf_stat)), as in `perf stat -r 10 -B sleep 1` (from https://superuser.com/a/1279724/129608)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 - [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/):**

create simple table with command and time columns, and view with proper [aggregation](http://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) calculations. After timing, [add a row](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) to the table.

Advantages: simpler to define a table compared to solution 2.

Disadvantages: you need (do you?) care about data retention.

**Option 2 - [rrdtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/):**

Define rrd data base file, data definition and aggregation functions.
After timing, feed the database with `rrdtool update ...`.

Advantages: you can easily generate graphs with `rrdtool graph ...`. No data retention issue (round robin database).

Disadvantages: bit harder to define rrd database compared to simple SQL table/view